# How to determine the exact bounds of a Text composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to draw a custom composable (in the example below it is a `Spacer`) that has exactly the same dimensions as the glyphs of a `Text` composable, e.g.:

[image: desired appearance]

With the code below, however, the `Spacer` also fills whitespace above, below, left and right of the actual text:

[image: actual appearance]

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    Box(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min).height(IntrinsicSize.Max)){
        Spacer(Modifier.background(Color(0xFFFFCCCC)).fillMaxSize())
        Text("abc")
    }
}
```

I also tried using the `TextMeasurer` api, but that does not change the result:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun WithTextMeasurerPreview() {
    val measurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val measurement = measurer.measure("abc")
    val sizePx = measurement.size.toSize()
    val width = with (LocalDensity.current) { sizePx.width.toDp() }
    val height = with (LocalDensity.current) { sizePx.height.toDp() }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)){
        Spacer(
            Modifier
                .size(width, height)
                .background(Color(0xFFFFCCCC))
                )
        Text("abc")
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that the `Spacer` has exactly the same bounding box as the glyphs in the `Text`?

Answer (score -1):

I would use the modifier `onGloballyPositioned` to get the text size and store it into a state variable, and use that state variable as the size of your `Spacer` (or whatever other Composable function you want). For example:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun WithOnGloballyPositionedPreview() {
    Box {
        var textSize by remember { mutableStateOf(DpSize.Zero) }
        val density = LocalDensity.current

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(textSize)
                .background(Color(0xFFFFCCCC)),
        )

        Text(
            text = "abc",
            modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned { coords ->
                    with(density) {
                        textSize = DpSize(
                            width = coords.size.width.toDp(),
                            height = coords.size.height.toDp(),
                        )
                    }
                },
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but unfortunately, the value of `textSize` includes whitespace around the text and therefore yields the same result as `TestPreview`.